# Нужны ли вопросы в стиле "что нового в новой версии продукта"?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, самоответы

Вышла новая версия некоего пакета. В нём заявлены новшества (what's new). Описание не всегда понятно и удобоваримо, а зачастую кратко и неинформативно. Имеет ли смысл (если ты уже имел отношения третьего вида с новинками, разобрался и поймал "Фа") публиковать расширенное описание и новые подходы, разумеется, с примерами кода? Да, это будет "вопрос, на который ты сам дал ответ", что, похоже, не очень приветствуется.
Меня, конечно, немного смущает следующее: в новой версии может быть много нововведений, а автор разобрался лишь с некоторыми (остальные, допустим, ему неинтересны). С другой стороны, кто-то иной может заполнить проблемы вторым ответом и так далее...

Ах, да, добавлю ещё один момент: языковой. Принято считать, что программист обязан знать "письменный английский", чтобы читать руководства. Отмечу, что минимум четверть владеет таковым от слова "никак", еще четверть - так себе, но это не позволяет им полностью понимать руководство, и эта четверть предпочитает русскоязычные мануалы (моя статистика - на базе студентов, аспирантов и вновь набираемых сотрудников). Да, программист, возможно, не должен знать язык на уровне учёного, но порой и у того, и у другого есть с этим проблемы. А тут - русскоязычное решение :)

Comment: _это будет "вопрос, на который ты сам дал ответ", что, похоже, не очень приветствуется_ - вопросы с самоответами приветствуются. Не приветствуются плохие вопросы и плохие ответы ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Имхо — не нужны. На enSO некоторые подобные вопросы закрывались ([раз](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58497280), [два](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19612278), [три](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096696))

Comment: @andreymal кстати, во всех трёх упомянутых случаях вопросы не имеют самоответов.

Answer (score 8):

Наверное, всё будет зависеть от качества и уникальности ответа, а также его востребованности (как часто на него будут приходить из поисковиков и ссылаться из других сообщений). При этом ответ должен получиться не слишком громадной портянкой, которую за один присест сложно прочитать и осознать. И, конечно же, не представлять из себя машинный перевод, несмотря на то, что с каждым годом он и становится лучше.

Предположу, что в случае серьёзных нововведений в продукте/технологии/языке лучшим вариантом может оказаться не полный перебор всего, что изменилось, а попытка сосредоточиться на чём-то более конкретном. Достаточно выбрать подходящие метки, например, указав соответствующую версионную метку, чтобы можно было связать вопросы друг с другом. Или даже использовать кросс-ссылки между сообщениями.

У меня, например, есть [самоответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/662431/176217), который, как мне кажется, подпадает под текущую рассматриваемую ситуацию. Правда при этом, планируется его обновлять по мере развития языка, а не фиксировать на состоянии, данном при первой публикации.

Comment: Этот самоответ хотя бы фокусируется на одной конкретной штуке "атрибуты", а не вообще любых новых фишках C++